# Is it possible to start "while read" a file that is currently being written? (and will the entirety of the file be read?)

Tags: bash

I have two bash processes that I normally launch after each other.
The first one appends line after line in a file.
The second one reads line after line, with the bash code:

```
while read document; do
        IFS=' ' read -r -a line <<< "$document"

        PROCESSING
done
```

From what I understood, I can launch the second process before the end of the first.
Let's assume the first process is slower than the second, I am wondering if:

- the whole document is only loaded once in "while read document" in the second process, and not updated afterward, thus resulting in only one part of the results of the first process to be treated by the second

OR

- the document is loaded line by line in the second process, and thus the second process will be able to read the whole ouput of the first process

?

Comment: `read` operates character-by-character, stopping when it hits a newline.

Comment: ...it smells like you don't actually _have_ a problem -- note our guidelines that questions should be about a "specific problem you actually face". The question of "do I have a problem at all?" can/should be answered before posting.

Comment: That said, putting `IFS=' ' read -r -a line <<< "$document"` inside the body of your loop is quite inefficient (every time you use `<<<"something"` it creates a new temporary file and writes `something` to it). Have you considered making your outer loop `while IFS=' ' read -r -a line; do ...`, so you're reading _directly_ into the array, instead of reading first into string?

Comment: Another thing to consider is that the outer `while read document` doesn't have a `-r` on it, so it'll munge literal backslashes in your input; that you're using `-r` later stops backslashes that survived the _first_ `read` from getting munged in the second, but it doesn't put them back.

Comment: You should also consider asking "how can I robustly produce lines in one script and consume them in another?" because it's very easy to do this safely and robustly without worrying about the reader being too fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` operates incrementally, a character at a time. It won't care whether a line is available in a file until it actually tries to read that specific line.

Thus, if your writer is writing *and actually flushing its buffers* faster than your reader reads, and appending to the same file in-place (rather than following a write-and-rename pattern), a reader won't know or care that content wasn't available yet when it first started execution.